# pd.DataFrame from an array in 2 different ways

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

im getting started with machine learning so i gave a try to MINST from kaggle. Im really curious about how things work so, as i couldn't find the answer online, thought it would be a great idea to make my first post in here.

i did a simple model with CNN on keras.This would be the prediction with the output from google colab.

```
Ynew =model.predict_classes(test_data)
Ynew.shape
```

(28000,)

```
Ynew
```

array([2, 0, 9, ..., 3, 9, 2])

Now i try to make a DataFrame from this and i don't really understand why i can make it one way and not the other.

This one works fine i get a table for 28000x2:

```
labels = ["ImageId","Label"]
col= list(range(1,28001))
submission=pd.DataFrame({"ImageId":col,"Label":Ynew})
```

But on this one i get everything cramped up in only 1 row:

```
submission2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[col,Ynew]],columns=labels)
```

Shouldn't both ways work the same?
Hope the post wasn't so bad and thank you!!

Comment: In the second way, you might have too many brackets. data = [col, Ynew] ??

Comment: thank you @bakka i tried without the double brackets but i get the error "2 columns passed, passed data had 28000 columns". I also changed the range(1,28001) not including list command. any idead??

Comment: yes you're right. doing [col, Ynew] will give list of lists that equals to array of (2, 28000). You may modify the list, but I think it's easier to create 2D-ndarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframe can be created from:

1. dict of dict of 1D-ndarrays, lists, dicts, or Series
2. 2-D numpy.ndarray
3. Structured or record ndarray
4. A Series
5. Another DataFrame

Ref: [pandas-docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

In your case, `Ynew` is a 1D-ndarray, and `loc` is a list. IMHO, you can only create dataframe from dict of `Ynew` and `loc` as what you've done in the 1st method.

For second method, you need to make `Ynew` and `loc` become 2D-ndarray.

```
d = np.vstack([loc,Ynew]).T  # you will have (28000,2)
submission2=pd.DataFrame(data = d, columns=labels)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the time you dedicated to my issue. that worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
submission2=pd.DataFrame(data=Ynew, index=col, columns=labels)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i tried this with minor adjustments (i couldn't use labels as it has 2 elements ) and got this result.  `submission2=pd.DataFrame(data=Ynew,index=col,columns=["labels"])`  `submission2.index.rename("ImageID", inplace=True)`  In practice it worked perfectly, but kaggle won't let me upload a file with index, i would need 2 columns.